# Which parts of an airplane are made of buoyant material?

Tags: aerospace-materials

Which parts of an airplane (to make this question more specific: accessible in the main fuselage where the passengers are aboard) are made of buoyant material.

Imagine a plane is about to crash into the sea, you might wanna hang on to something that could keep you afloat, so here’s a few things that I think are buoyant(based on the floating debris seen after a crash):

1. The life vest/jackets which we can inflate
2. Seats
3. The doors(the ones through which we enter or any other door)

Which things would someone want to hold onto, to increase chances of survival?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passengers are reminded of #1 & 2 above on every safety brief.

Beyond that, you aren't going to get up out of your seat before the crash and attempt to latch on to some buoyant part of the structure, so it isn't an actionable question in the context it is asked.  (Which is a polite way of saying who cares...)

Stay in your seat until the violent motion stops, then follow the instructions of the surviving crew to evacuate the aircraft in an orderly manner.

Allow women and children to go first if able.  Whatever might be floating after the crash is over is buoyant, and may be used.

Comment: I know that the odds of something like this to occur are quite low, but let’s say that since we are aviation geeks and we know when an aircraft would have a massive hit killing all passengers on impact, we could at least try something to increase our chances of survival, by running to the end of the aircraft(for reducing the force impact) and latch yourself to something buoyant to prevent drowning while unconscious, why not try doing something like this, I mean what do we have to lose

Comment: @Valay_17 You have your life to lose. Even the most gentle ditching is likely to be fairly violent. You're much more likely to survive the initial impact, and have fewer major injuries, if you're seated with your seat belt fastened. Given the typical speed of an aircraft, "running backward" isn't going to make hardly any practical difference in impact force, and will do absolutely nothing for sideways and vertical forces.

Comment: Or, if you survive, you are brought up on charges for failure to obey the crew and endangering other passengers for your selfish and desperate actions.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield Running backwards as in go the end of the aircraft(and brace for impact) to reduce the head on impact(which might be enough to not knock someone unconscious). Also gentle ditching isn’t the case, I am assuming we have lost an engine/control and it is going to be quite rough where definitely the odds of survival are at the lower spectrum but maybe something that we do might increase our chances.

Comment: @Valay_17, so if everyone runs to the back at the same time does CG shift and the airplane stall?  Not everyone will fit, so you start fighting?  How do you know whether it will be survivable or not?  (Miracle on the Hudson)  Personally I would rather stay in my seat and die with dignity than scramble as you propose.  And if you were to try this you risk getting throat punched by a burly passenger in assistance of the crew.  I would, and I'm not burly...

Comment: @MichaelHall Not everyone would do that, and those who do would help each other, I mean survival is important so. Again this is something that has the least probability to happen, also it is gonna happen so fast people won’t have time to react to thus but rather focus on survival.

Comment: Survival of EVERYONE is important.  So, stay in your seat!!!

Comment: As an self-proclaimed aviation geek, @Valay_17, you should know that being tightly strapped into your seat gives you the best chance of surviving the initial impact. _If_ you survive that, then you find anything floating and grab hold of that. If you're bobbing in the sea, you're really not going to care one bit what floating thing you're holding on to. You're just hoping the sharks go after the ones leaving blood trails and that you're not one of them.

Comment: @Valay_17 (1/2) There's a video (I can't find it right now, so no link) demonstrating the need for child seats. In it, a bodybuilder tried to hold on to a child dummy in an actual 30 mph (50 km/h) car crash (obviously the guy was strapped in tightly, had a helmet, etc.). Even though he was curled up around the dummy as tight as possible, he wasn't able to hold on to it, and the dummy exited the car through the windshield. Now, if a _bodybuilder_ can't even do that much, do you really think you're going to be able to hold on to **anything at all** in a 160 mph (250 km/h) crash?

Comment: @Valay_17 (2/2) Studies have shown that being in the back of the plane is, generally speaking, safer than being in the front. I think that's where you're getting the "run to the back" idea from. But, you see, those studies implicitly assume that everyone's safely strapped into their seats, not running around the cabin while failing to hold on to random crap. That is a much, _much_, **much** more dangerous place than seated with your seatbelt fastened, even if said seat is in the very front row.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield 1/2 - Yup got your point. 2/2 - Yes, that’s exactly where the “run to the back” idea comes from. I understand the concern of you guys explaining me that seatbelts are there for a reason and I do agree and I am not against them at all.

Comment: @Valay_17 In the miracle on the Hudson the back of the plane sank fairly quickly and the rear seats are farthest from the exit. Unless the plane noses down into the water I'd say the back is not the safest place to be. If the plane broke in half the rear would likely sink like a rock.

Comment: Downvoted because - in addition to all the good points made in comments - the question simply can't be answered unless you know the specific type of plane, and details of its construction.  E.g. I would imagine that something like a LongEZ, with its foam core construction, might float very well.